# Annotations with Latex don't render in Okular

Tags: texlive, okular

I have TeX Live 2020 installed and it works. Unfortunately, my Typewriter annotations in Okular don't work with latex code.

After making a simple annotation `$$a$$` and clicking to render it, I have an error that Okular cannot find latex executable.

This has nothing to do with forward/backward searches, these actually work with my vimtex where I usually compile tex files.

I do have latex executable available. Trying `tex -version` and `latex -version` on terminal I can see outputs (versions are `TeX 3.14159265` and `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21`).

How to make okular see my latex executables? I cannot find any relevant configs.

Comment: I'm not sure (I don't have a recent version of Okular to test) but maybe you can find something in the Settings-Backend Settings menu?

Comment: I checked and there is nothing in regard to latex.. btw. my version of okular is 1.10.0

Comment: I know nothing about okular but are you starting it from the same shell in which you set the PATH to find latex

Comment: yes I do.. Moreover the terminal (with the same shell) from which I run okular doesn't print any warnings/errors related to latex when it fails to render annotations

Comment: I don’t understand what you are trying to do. Where and how do you type annotations? Please elaborate.

Comment: @KeksDose do you use okular? There is a specific type of annotation called Typewriter in okular. This creates a textbox which should have capability to render latex using `$$...$$` delimiters. In a sample pdf (whatever the file) I select this annotation in okular (under reviews bar which opens with `F6`) and just type arbitrary `$$a$$` in a textbox that pop-ups. It detects latex code and shows up an option to click and render it. However once clicked, the error shows up that latex executable is not found and just raw text is displayed. Which part do I need to elaborate on?

Comment: OK, found it, works: As soon as I type something in this kind of annotation between two pairs of $$, okular offers to render it using LaTeX. I found I can write text by typing `$$\text{\bfseries\Large Text}$$ and after clicking on the hint, it will be rendered as text inside a math environment. This might be usefull if you'd like to add math to your PDF. Can you please post the whole error message you are getting?

Comment: Does this here help: https://lists.debian.org/debian-kde/2018/04/msg00058.html

Comment: What happened? Can we either solve your issue or close the question?

Comment: My problem isn't solved. In the link you provided, the guy just had to install `texlive-latex-base` and then some other missing package. In my case, I already have tex live so this doesn't help. I tried reinstalling tex live, because before I had a minimal version. Now i have plain texlive-latex-base from package repository and the error persists.

Comment: btw. I want to add math to pdf, exactly the feature you mention. The exact error is 
`LaTeX rendering failed
Cannot find latex executable`
Nothing more than I already wrote :( not too verbose.. @KeksDose what Tex distribution do you have? I'm thinking about installing `texlive-full`, but this is unlikely to solve the issue..

Comment: What do you get in a terminal as anwser to `which pdflatex`(plus ENTER, of course)

Comment: `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`

Comment: OK, perfect. So maybe you have an old version of okular, which might be buggy? Here `okular --version` gets `okular 1.10.0` as answer. Besides the idea that okular was buggy, I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 has KDE Applications 17.12.3 with okular 1.3.3, while the Typewriter annotations were released with okular 1.6 (KDE Applications 18.12). As the default okular from ubuntu 18.04 package repository doesn't have the Typewriter, I installed the other okular option available in Ubuntu Software - the newest okular 1.10 (KDE 20.04). Turns out that this version is from Snap Store and installs itself via snap. This is the setup in which okular wasn't able to render latex in Typewriter annotations. Most likely there is something wrong with the snap installation of okular.

I upgraded to ubuntu 19.10 which has KDE Applications 19.043 and okular 1.7.3 in the package repository. I installed this okular from package repository and now latex executables are found. Typewriter annotations with latex formulas do render.

I'm not entirely sure if the okular from snap is the culprit but beware of installing okular available in Ubuntu software (snap one) if you want to use latex in annotations. It's probably better to build okular from sources or to update OS to have a more recent version of okular installed from package manager.

ps. now that rendering latex in annotations works for me, I'm super disappointed. Turns out that in the viewer, Typewriter annotations are just raw text with tex code, which I must click to open a pop-up and only there I must manually render each annotation.. Completely unpractical, I was sure that these would be rendered in the viewer by default, but no.

Comment: Yes, I agree, not a useful gimick. However, thanks to your question I found out that okular now can annotate PDFs in a better way than before, the annotations are saved in the PDF and not, as before, in an extra file.

Comment: Yep okular seems as the best linux option to have annotations in the pdf. Too bad annotations with tex math can't be rendered automatically, that would be all I need.. Lack of this functionality means I must abandon the idea of annotations in pdf and paste images with formulas in xournal (okular doesn't have option to insert images into pdf afaik)

Comment: I bought pdf master editor for such things, but recently it lacks some attention by the manufacturer. However, often useful.